# Recalculate group height after window resize

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have an AIR application.
In this application, several mxml files for each windows.
Each window has height and width. 
When window opening, I access to an user preference file to use height and width preference for this windows.
This action is done on creationcomplete step.
Window is resizing correctly but not his content. For example a datagrid inside this window is bigger that windows.
But when I resize with gripper the window, datagrid is resize. So can you help me to resize all children when window is opening.
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the command `stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));` within the creationComplete (I wonder if this will cause an infinite loop, though).

Comment: Hi, with your tips the windows is not resizing. Thanks

Comment: From the Adobe docs [Listening for window events](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e07.html) "For NativeWindowDisplayStateEvent events, you can use the beforeDisplayState and afterDisplayState properties to determine the window display state before and after the impending or completed change."  I would recommend trying to listen for that event, and seeing when it happens, and what has happened to the inner windows at that point.  Sorry I'm not much help on Air yet. . . .

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you dispatch a resize event on creationcomplete

```
this.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));
```

Or, if you use relative sizes for your components (`width="50%"` etc) or anchor the edges to the application (`left="10" top="100" right="50" bottom="10"` etc) then it should resize even otherwise without the resize event being dispatched.

Comment: Hi with you tips this error appear Thread principal (Suspendu : TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::Event@1f04df39 to flash.events.NativeWindowBoundsEvent.) 
 flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction[aucune source] 
 flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent[aucune source] 
 fr.intersystemes.ui.display._36Contact::wContactsPat/wcustomwindow1_creationCompleteHandler 
 fr.intersystemes.ui.display._36Contact::wContactsPat/___wContactsPat_wCustomWindow1_creationComplete

Comment: jeez....then dispatch a `NativeWindowBoundsEvent` like: `this.dispatchEvent(new NativeWindowBoundsEvent(NativeWindowBoundsEvent.RESIZE));`

Comment: Hi, I try to use this.dispatchEvent(new NativeWindowBoundsEvent(NativeWindowBoundsEvent.RESIZE)), but there is no effect. My main container, group type is not resizing.